# ConstraintLyaout GONE view doesn't affect constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I've this layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text2"
        android:text="Left"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text2"
        android:text="Right"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I change the visibility of the center and left textviews to gone, The right textview still remains on the right side, instead of being pulled to the left side since it's constraints are gone.

Any idea why?

Comment: It seems the android:id="@+id/text2" is constrained with parents (start and end), and the other textviews are constrained with it in some way (start or end). It creates a strange dependency. I suppose it's because it will not know how to show it correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Eguti

I tried changing the center textview constraint with a guideline, and still it didn't work, it behaves the same.

The idea is that I need the second textview always be centered and the side textviews to align to it

Comment: At the moment the center text visibility is gone, what it's suppose to happen?

Comment: I expect the the right view will be aligned to the left

Answer (score 2):

I fixed using a barrier and `app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"` and setting the right view constrained to the barrier

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text2"
        android:text="Left"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
        android:text="Right"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2"
        app:barrierDirection="end"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not expect the right view to be pulled all the way over to the left if you make the left and center views `gone`. When the views are made `gone`, they are shrunk to a point (zero width and height), but their constraints remain intact. In their `gone` state, the right view is constrained to the center view which is still at the center of the layout. See [Visibility Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#VisibilityBehavior). The diagram at this link is a little misleading since it may appear (it did to me, initially) that view "B" assumes the left constraint of view "A". That is not the case: All the constraints remain as they were before `gone` is applied.

That is the "why" and the answer to your question. There are probably several ways to fix it. One way that leaves your current layout intact is to change the horizontal bias of the center view to zero which will move it all the way to the left when the views are made `gone`. You will also make the right view's bias zero to move it all the way to the left, too. You will need to reset the biases to 50% if you make the views visible again.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I will recommend you to use LinearLayout and the property weightSum. So it will be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```